# Zend Framework 3 Model class invoke to get configuration of db

Tags: database, configuration, model, zend-framework3

I have these model-classes:

MasterModel:

```
namespace sf\ZfCommons\Model;

use Zend\Db\Sql\Sql;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;

class MasterModel extends AbstractModel
{
    public $db;
    public $dbSys;
    public $dbUserClient;
    public $dbSysParams;
    public $dbUserClientParams;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->dbSys = new Adapter(Array(
            'driver' => 'Pdo_Mysql',
            'hostname' => 'localhost',
            'database' => 'db1',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => 'password',
            'charset' => 'utf8'
            ));

        $this->dbUserClient = new Adapter(Array(
            'driver' => 'Pdo_Mysql',
            'hostname' => 'localhost',
            'database' => 'db2',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => 'password',
            'charset' => 'utf8'
            ));

        if ($this::TBL_PLACE == 'user_client') {
            $this->db = $this->dbUserClient;
        } else {
            $this->db = $this->dbSys;
        }
        $this->sql = new Sql($this->db);
    }
}
```

AbstractModel:

```
namespace sf\ZfCommons\Model;

use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager;

class AbstractModel
{
    /**
     * @var ServiceManager
     */
    protected $serviceManager;

    /**
     * @return ServiceManager
     */
    public function getServiceManager()
    {
        return $this->serviceManager;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $serviceManager
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setServiceManager(ContainerInterface $serviceManager)
    {
        $this->serviceManager = $serviceManager;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

ModelFactory:

```
namespace sf\ZfCommons\Model;

use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;

class ModelFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        echo "############# ModelFactory #################";

        $service = (null === $options) ? new $requestedName : new $requestedName($options);

        return $service->setServiceManager($container);
    }
}
```

My module.config.php has the lines:

```
...
'service_manager' => [
        'factories' => [
            \sf\ZfCommons\Model\MasterModel::class => \sf\ZfCommons\Model\ModelFactory::class
        ],
        'invokables' => [
        ],
    ],
...
```

But the Factory is not called...
What is wrong here?
I want to read the db1 and db2 params from the configuration and set 2 adapters ( for each db one adapter )

How can I do that? Is there another way to get the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

For your factory to be called, you need to use the Service Manager to get the `MasterModel` service where you need to use it, such as in another factory.  For example:

```
class SomethingFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
   public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
   { 
     $masterModel = $container->get(\sf\ZfCommons\Model\MasterModel::class);
     // then do something with $masterModel, like inject it into something else
     return new Something($masterModel);
   }
}
```

In addition, ZF has a built-in DB adapter abstract factory that can build both adapters for you without having to create the MasterModel class and its factory.  This is assuming that you are building a MVC application.

In your `config/autoload/local.php` or `config/autoload/global.php`, add the following:

```
'db' => [
    'adapters' => [
        'dbSys' => [
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'database' => 'db1',
            'driver' => 'Pdo_Mysql',
            'username' => 'username',
            'password' => 'password',
            'hostname' => 'localhost',
        ],
        'dbClient' => [
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'database' => 'db2',
            'driver' => 'Pdo_Mysql',
            'username' => 'username',
            'password' => 'password',
            'hostname' => 'localhost',
        ],
    ],
],
```

In your `module.config.php` (although it would be better to put this in the `config/autoload/global.php`), your can add these lines:

```
...
'service_manager' => [
     'factories' => [
         'dbSys' => \Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterAbstractServiceFactory::class,
         'dbClient' => \Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterAbstractServiceFactory::class,
     ],
     'invokables' => [
     ],
 ],
...
```

But you still need to user the Service Manager at one point to get the adapters.  Using the example above:

```
$dbSys = $container->get('dbSys);
$dbClient = $container->get('dbClient');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: if I have understood correctly, my classes are ok. but I must create SomethingFactory to get it work?

the second solution (ZF has a built-in DB adapter abstract factory) looks better. How can I get the $container-variable in a model or another class?

Comment: The SomethingFactory was an example.  The key point is that your are using a factory to create your class.  Anywhere you have access to the Service Manager, you can use it to create your class by calling $sm->get(\sf\ZfCommons\Model\MasterModel::class).  In a factory implementing FactoryInterface, the Service Manager comes as $container.

Comment: To answer your second question, it depends what you are trying to do.  Typically, you should not have to store the ServiceManager into your class, but rather create your class by injecting what you need into it.  As in the example that I gave, the factory is instantiating an object of your class.  The factory, when calling the constructor of your class, can inject whatever you need, including the ServiceManager ($container) if you want to.  Check the [Service Manager docs](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-servicemanager/) and related dependency injection methods